# MailKit not works in dotnet core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, mailkit

I am new to programming and I am building a web api project using dotnet core 5. I have installed MailKit in order to send emails, but it not works. Here are my configurations:

```
 services.AddMailKit(config =>
        {
            config.UseMailKit(configuration.GetSection("Email").Get<MailKitOptions>());
        });
```

Also my appsettings:

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "xxxxxxx"
  },
  "Email": {
    "Server": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 465,
    "SenderName": "xxxx",
    "SenderEmail": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "Account": "xxxx",
    "Password": "xxxx",
    "Security": true
  },
  "JWT": {
    "ValidAudience": "User",
    "ValidIssuer": "https://localhost:5001",
    "Secret": "aslkjsdfl;afa;falkajs"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

My gmail password and address is correct. Also I have enabled less secure apps in google account. Here is how I send emails:

```
await _emailService.SendAsync(user.Email, "Email Verification", emailVereificationLink);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Your code snippets aren't using any MailKit APIs at all (at least not directly), so I'm not even sure how MailKit is being used.

Comment: It does not send email. Do you need any more details?

Comment: Are messages not being sent because you are getting an exception? Or are you not getting any exceptions? If you aren't getting any exceptions, maybe the messages are being delivered to the user's spam folder.